# Detecting programmatically if "Restrict background data" is enabled for Android app

Tags: android, background-process

I searched stack overflow and could not find an answer to detect this setting set for my app. In Android Marshmallow there is an option in Settings :

Settings -> Data Usage -> My App -> Toggle for "Restrict app background data" which "disable background data on cellular network"

I want to warn the user if this set in my app. How can I detect if this is set for my app. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: found a solution to this?

Comment: Also how do I determine if background data has been disabled for the entire phone or just for my app?

Answer (score 6):

Per the latest android docs starting with Android 7.0 (API level 24)...

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver.html

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
// Checks if the device is on a metered network
if (connMgr.isActiveNetworkMetered()) {
  // Checks user’s Data Saver settings.
  switch (connMgr.getRestrictBackgroundStatus()) {
    case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_ENABLED:
    // Background data usage is blocked for this app. Wherever possible,
    // the app should also use less data in the foreground.

    case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_WHITELISTED:
    // The app is whitelisted. Wherever possible,
    // the app should use less data in the foreground and background.

    case RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_STATUS_DISABLED:
    // Data Saver is disabled. Since the device is connected to a
    // metered network, the app should use less data wherever possible.
  }
} else {
  // The device is not on a metered network.
  // Use data as required to perform syncs, downloads, and updates.
}
```

> Monitoring Changes to Data Saver Preferences
>   Apps can monitor changes to Data Saver preferences by creating a BroadcastReceiver to listen for ConnectivityManager.ACTION_RESTRICT_BACKGROUND_CHANGED and dynamically registering the receiver with Context.registerReceiver(). When an app receives this broadcast, it should check if the new Data Saver preferences affect its permissions by calling ConnectivityManager.getRestrictBackgroundStatus().
>
> Note: The system only sends this broadcast to apps that dynamically register for them with Context.registerReceiver(). Apps that register to receive this broadcast in their manifest will not receive them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `getActiveNetworkInfo()`

> When background data is unavailable, getActiveNetworkInfo() will now
>   appear disconnected.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting())

**fyi:**

According to Android reference, `getBackgroundDataSetting`

> Returns the value of the setting for background data usage. If false,
>   applications should not use the network if the application is not in
>   the foreground.

However this was deprecated in API level 14.

Comment: The problem with the getActiveNetworkInfo() is that it is connected when you are on wifi. It does not tell you if the app has the background setting disabled for Cellular.. :(